# Asset prices are in theory log-normally distributed

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution, finance

In finance, the price of an asset is given by the following formula.

$P_t=P_0* e^r$

r=returns
Pt = Price at time "t".
P0 = Actual Price.

Likewise, it is assumed that the yields (r) will follow a normal distribution with mean $u$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

so, the distribution functions
$$
F_p(p) = P(p_t\le p_t)=P(p_0 *e^r\le p_t)=P(e^r\le \frac{pt}{p_0}) =P(r<=\ln(\frac{P_t}{P_0})) = F_r(r=\ln(\frac{P_t}{P_0}))
$$
To obtain the density function and using the chain rule, we derive the distribution functions,

$$
f_p(p)=f_r(\ln(\frac{P_t}{P_0}))*\frac{1}{P_t}$$
By hypothesis we have that the density function of r follows a normal with zero mean and variance sigma squared, then

$$=>\frac{1}{P_t\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp\{-(\ln(\frac{P_t}{P_0})^2/(2\sigma^2)\}$$
Applying the logarithm property, we have

$$=>\frac{1}{P_t\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp-\{(\ln(P_t)-\ln(P_0))^2/(2\sigma^2)\},
$$
Concluding that
,  $P_t \sim \text{LogNormal}(\ln(P_0), \sigma^2)$.

Is this derivation of price theory in finance correct?
That is, prices are distributed lognormally with mean $\ln(P_o)$ and variance $(\sigma^2)$.
I ask the question because a log-normal distribution has mean = $\exp^(u+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})$  and not $\ln(x)$

Comment: You don't have to do any algebra at all: your problem statement is the usual definition of a lognormal distribution.